# Looking for a way to run a command depending on OS version

Tags: bash, script

I'm trying to create a bash script that runs a command based on OS version that way I can deploy it to machines running 10.12 and 10.13 the only problem is depending on the version the command needs to be slightly different.  How can I go about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913942/check-version-of-os-then-issue-a-command-if-the-correct-version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the OS version using `sw_vers -productVersion`.

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.13.2
```

You can test on this in a shell script using

```
if [[ $(sw_vers -productVersion) == 10.13.2 ]]; then …
```

To test any 10.12 or 10.13 version, you can use parse the output such as with this

```
if [[ $(sw_vers -productVersion | sed "s/10\.\([0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/") == 13 ]]; then …
```